# How to use wordpress theme with .net core react app?

Tags: .net, reactjs, asp.net-core

I can't figure how to inject a wordpress theme on my .net core/react app. I know there is the wwroot css and react css but dont know if i need to put the css copy paste in two places and if thats the correct way or is there an easier way.

For example: https://usebootstrap.com/theme/eshop you get all the html/css/js

Comment: Did I understand correctly, that you want to use a _wordpress_ theme on a _non-wordpress_ application?

Comment: the css/js behind it only, so yes